# Bind events firing twice in Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have this code written which will read a CSV file and add items to a SharePoint List. It is working but it is adding the same items twice. It adds from top to bottom then it adds again whole items.

It reads the items correctly and adds correctly as well. But I am not able to figure out why the code runs two times.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#upload").bind("click", function() {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
    if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
      if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {

          var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");

          console.log(rows);
          for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

            var cells = rows[i].split("|");
            var item = {
              "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Data.TestCatalogListItem"
              },
              "Title": cells[0],
              "CityTitle": cells[1],
              "FirstName": cells[3],
              "LastName": cells[4]

            }

            _createListItem(item);

          }

        }

        reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);

      } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
    }
  });
});



function _createListItem(listItems, success, failure) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://mysite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('TestCatalog')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(listItems),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //success(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      //failure(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</body>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the answer.
So this is what I ended up doing.

Replace

```
$("#upload").bind("click", function () {
```

with

```
$("#upload").unbind("click").click(function (){
```

Things are working now :)

Comment: Any idea what the issue was and why this helped?

Answer (score 0):

may be your binding event script runs twice so, ended up adding click event twice.
You can name the event by a unique string, so that it wont bind the event twice.

```
$("#upload").bind("click.uniqueName", function() {
    // your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your ajax call add **async: false** in your ajax call. this is because your for loop will execute before completing your ajax request. so better to add this thing. else you can use jQuery deferred. your code is working fine. and your event is attached only one time.

```
function _createListItem(listItems, success, failure) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://mysite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('TestCatalog')/items",
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(listItems),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //success(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      //failure(data);
    }
  });
}
```